# Extracting information from list based on string, not item position in Emacs

Tags: list, emacs

I would like to select the value from initial-frame-alist, namely the number after width:

initial-frame-alist `evals` to `"((top . 1) (left . 1) (width . 50) (height . 30)))"`

I would like to extract the 50, from width. The problem is that for other people this setup might be different, i.e. width would be the first instead of third item (and thus `car` and the like won't work; positions can be different.

How can I select the part from the list (width . 50) (possibly based on the string "width") after which it is possible to select the second item?

More illustrative example:

`(car initial-frame-alist)` evaluates to `(top . 1)`

`(car (car initial-frame-alist))` evaluates to `top`

EDIT: It would also be possible not to care about the list structure, but to treat it as a string, though I would not know how to go about it then either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(cdr (assoc 'width initial-frame-alist))
```

`assoc` is the way to go with alist; it is different from just any list; it is an association list.